# Header wrapping on markdown in RStudio

Tags: r, r-markdown

I would like to split the column headers of a table. I've already looked at this note https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html, but I haven't found answers to my issue. I've tried to use the `column_spec` but didn't work. Also, I would like to highlight the column headers through a color.

Here below a example:

````
---
title: "Report"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
```

```{r}
options(knitr.table.format = "html") 
```

```{r}
text_tbl <- data.frame(
  Items = c("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"),
  Features = c(
"Description 1",
"Description 2",
"Description 3"
)
)
names(text_tbl)[2]="Column name to break"
kable(text_tbl, "html") %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold = T, border_right = T) %>%
  column_spec(2, width = "30em")
```
````

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Try to decrease the width for column 2 a little and use row_spec(0, ...) for the header row.

```
kable(text_tbl, "html") %>%
 kable_styling(full_width = F) %>%
 column_spec(1, bold = T, border_right = T) %>%
 column_spec(2, width = "8em") %>%
 row_spec(0, color = "red")
```

Comment: Hello Hao,
Thanks for answering. Is there a way just to break the title of column and keep the column width? I ask that because some column names is a little long.

I really appreciate any answers.